# Create Core class that can be used in more than one .h file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Im starting to learn Xcode (Objective c) and im orginal c#/vb programmer
im faceing the following problem i can't find the right answhere

When i create an .h file like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Core : NSObject

@property BOOL *DebugMode;

@end

@implementation Core

-(void)SetDebugMode:(BOOL*)Debug
{
  self.DebugMode = Debug;
}

@end
```

if i want to use the class in another 2 .h files (like UIViewController)
i access it by

```
Core *cr = [[Core alloc]init];
```

it comes up with the following Error:

```
 Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Core", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

i also tryed to use them in AppDelegate.m
what is the correct using of classes and methods in objective c
thank you very much for your tips and help.

I want one class to use everywhere in the .h UIViewcontroller code or somewhere else
so i can use general stuff like DebugMode etc. don't know how to do it in xcode

Kind Regards,
Stefan.

Answer (score 0):

You need to #import the header file at the top of the files you want to use it in, above the interface:

```
#împort "Core.h"
```

Your .h files are **only** public API, they should not contain implementations. That is what your .m file is for. In other words, your .h file should look like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Core : NSObject

@property (nonatomic) BOOL DebugMode;

@end
```

and your .m file (the implementation) should look like this:

```
#import "Core.h"

@interface Core()

// Any private properties you want

@end

@implementation Core

-(void)setDebugMode:(BOOL)DebugMode
{
  _DebugMode = DebugMode;
}

@end
```

Then, when you're ready to set DebugMode, you add `#import "Core.h"` at the top of the file in which you would like to access it, and set it like this:

```
Core *co = [[Core alloc] init];
co.DebugMode = foo; // NOTE: You can access this @property (DebugMode) from a different class because it is in your public .h file.
```

NOTE: Do not use an asterisk with BOOL:

```
-(void)SetDebugMode:(BOOL*)DebugMode // This is wrong.
-(void)setDebugMode:(BOOL)DebugMode // This is correct.
```

You should also start properties with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

You should write

```
-(void)SetDebugMode:(BOOL*)Debug
{
  self.DebugMode = Debug;
}
```

in .m file, and make your .h file look like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Core : NSObject

@property BOOL *DebugMode;

@end

@implementation Core

-(void)SetDebugMode:(BOOL*)Debug; //only name

@end
```

after that you can call it like you do

```
Core *cr = [[Core alloc]init];
[cr SetDebugMode:foo];
```

- in obj-c you better start method names with lowercase to avoid confusing with classes :)